# Finding a basis for a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to understand bases in linear algebra and I am wondering for a simple problem such as $V = \{\,(x,1+x) \mid x \in \mathbb{R} \,\}$, to find a basis for $V$ could I simply make it $\{(0,1)\}$ and be done or do I need more to consider it a complete basis since $(0,1)$ is linearly independent?
Any help or explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! $V$ is not a vector space.

Comment: Also i don't think that 0 can be part of a basis

Comment: sorry x is supposed to be a vector, not just a real number

Comment: V is still probably not a vector space, and it's not clear exactly how you're defining it. As a quick sanity check, remember that all vector spaces contain the zero vector.

Comment: (At least with the usual operations) $V$ is not a vector space, as e.g. it doesn't contain the zero vector.

Answer (score 1):

There is something incorrect with the way you have posed the question as $V$ as defined above is not a vector space.

However, suppose your vector space $V$ is the space of degree $1$ polynomials.

You could choose $\{x, 1+x\}$ to be your basis.

$x$ and $1+x$ are linearly independent, and these two polynomials indeed span the space.

There is not the only basis you could choose.

$\{1,x\}$ would also be an example of a suitable basis.